# Align image and text differently inside the same div

Tags: html, css

How do I align an image to the left (bullet point style) and the text to the center?
This is how they look:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/path/to/image.png') }}">
  TEX TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/path/to/image.png') }}">
  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
</div>
```

Right now, the `divs` have `text-align: left` and obviously both image and text go to the left, but I want them in the center of the div, with the images perfectly align verticaly.
[image: This is how it looks now][image: What i want]

Comment: Is it something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mu7gvLtq/

Comment: could you please provide a fiddle? its hard to understand what you want to do...

Comment: @Pangloss I tried that, but that doesn't make the image of the second div aligned vertically with the image above

Comment: @J.Sadi What I have looks like the first image attached (but instead of bullet points, I use images that look like a check inside a circle) and I want it to look like the second image attached. Basically looks the same, but aligned in the center with the images aligned perfectly bellow each other

Comment: This one with bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/073gzLLa/ and without https://jsfiddle.net/zbzbjxz8/

Comment: did you checked my edited answer? please mark es the right answer, if i solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could try vertical-align like this but you have to wrap the text in a span:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/path/to/image.png') }}">
  <span>TEX TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</span>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/path/to/image.png') }}">
  <span>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<span>
</div>

img, span{
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Ok thought you needed only vertical alignment. Try this:

**Updated answer:**

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="http://www.tevel.cn/en/images/apple/dot.png"> 
    <span>TEX TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="http://www.tevel.cn/en/images/apple/dot.png"> 
    <span>TEX TEXT TEXTT</span>
  </div>
</div>

img{
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-top:3px;
}
#wrap{
  text-align:center;
}
div{
  clear:both;
  margin-left:30px;
}
img, span{
  float:left;
}
```

Updated answer so that items stay always in the middle of the container horizontally:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="innerWrap">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/path/to/image.png') }}"> 
            <span>TEX TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/path/to/image.png') }}"> 
            <span>TEX TEXT TEXTT</span>
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>

    #wrap{
    text-align:center;
    }
    #innerWrap{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    img,span{
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    .col-sm-6{
        text-align: left;
    }
```

Comment: They keep aligned to the left of the div

Comment: Well, this actually works fine for a static screen, but when the browser window is increasing in width, it stays in the same spot. The goal is to be responsive to stay in the middle for every screen size

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap (i think so), should this work for you:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/path/to/image.png') }}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
      TEX TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/path/to/image.png') }}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
      TEX TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
```

Working example: http://www.bootply.com/RqjSoFQEOU

> Bootstrap grid documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

---

If you're not using bootstrap you could do something like this:

```
<div style="text-align: left; width: 400px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/path/to/image.png') }}">
    TEX TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/path/to/image.png') }}">
    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jqg7s839/1/

> if you want to use the second solution with bootstrap, you should remove the col-sm-6 classes, ore both will be in one line.. (6+6 = 12) read bootstraps grid documentation for more informations. :)

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated. I think deprecated is a slow term, in my opinion is dead. Don't use old markups, like `<center>`,  `<marquee>` and so on, it's discouraged.

Comment: I am indeed using bootstrap, but like @Alex 's answeer, it's working only for a unique window size

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Both solutions should work on each window-size. take a look at it. please mark as the right answer, if i solved your issue :)